# Python XLSXWriter: getting writer from workbook

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am trying to build automation to build excel reports using Pandas and xlsxwriter. I pass the writer to functions to be able to add worksheets and etc. I then return the writer back, which inevitably gets passed into another function and the workbook is taken out again. Example as below

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine="xlsxwriter")
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='first_sheet')
def test_func(excel_writer):
    workbook = excel_writer.book
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('second_sheet')
    *Do something with the worksheet*
    return excel_writer
writer = test_func(writer)
writer.close()
```

The dataframe passed in has data in it already, within the function I do some formatting and adding of more data. However the excel file that saves is empty. My thought is that the return of the writer from the function is the issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`df.to_excel()` does not return a writer. You need to instance one yourself.

```
def test_func(excel_writer):
    workbook = excel_writer.book
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("second_sheet")
    # *Do something with the worksheet*
    return excel_writer


# Use with block to auto-close after operation is finished
with pd.ExcelWriter("sample.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="first_sheet")
    writer = test_func(writer)
```

Comment: Thank you! However I can pass a writer, break it down into workbooks / worksheets, then return the overall writer again from the function?

Comment: I believe the code does what you are asking. If you wish to perform more actions with the writer, you have it keep it within the `with` block, otherwise the writer will be closed.